# How do java generic methods constrain the method type arguments?

Tags: java, generics

I've been reading about generic methods, and thought I understood how the generic type argument would constrain the method parameter types, but when I tested out some of the ideas with actual code, I got unexpected results. Here is a simple generic method that I don't understand:

```
private static <T> void foo(T[] t1, T[] t2){  
    t2[0] = t1[0];
}
...
String[] stringArray = new String[]{"1", "2", "3"};
Integer[] integerArray = new Integer[]{4,5,6};
foo(stringArray, integerArray);
```

I would have thought that this generic method was constrained so that the two arrays had to be of the same type T, but in practice the code above compiles just fine, even though one array is of type String and the other is of type Integer.  When the program runs, it generates a run-time exception (ArrayStoreException).

Comment: I'm not a java expert but I'm guessing the parser can't tell that foo() accepts 2 type T[]s that have to be the same. It sees String[] is a type T[] and an Integer[] is also a type T[]. Which exactly should it use as T?

Comment: Good answers all 'round. Well done SO'ers.

Comment: @CurtainDog Many thanks we do our best ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In this example the inferred type is `? extends Object[]`, which fits both types.

In order to achieve what you want, you'd need:

```
private static <T> void foo(Class<T> clazz, T[] t1, T[] t2);
```

then

```
foo(String.class, stringArray, stringArray); // compiles
foo(String.class, stringArray, integerArray); // fails
```

Answer (score 1):

A not-so-well-known fact about Java is that `String[]` is a subtype of `Object[]` (in contrast to `List<String>` not being a subtype of `List<Object>`). Hence the compiler can infer `T` = `Object`, making the method signature

```
foo(Object[] t1, Object[] t2)
```

which can be called with `foo(stringArray, integerArray)`.

If you try the same with Lists:

```
<T> void foo(List<T> t1, List<T> t2) { ... }
```

you will find that

```
foo(new ArrayList<String>(), new ArrayList<Integer>())
```

doesn't compile - because there is no `T` such that both `List<String>` and `List<Integer>` are subtypes of `List<T>`. However, if instead you used wildcard types to declare the method:

```
void foo(List<?> t1, List<?> t2) { ... }
```

the method could be invoked (but the method body won't compile, because the compiler knows that the `?` may refer to incompatible types).

Comment: String extends Object is a 'not-so-well-known fact'?

Comment: Covariance of arrays is surprising to some - after all it violates Liskov's substitution priciple (neccessitating the existence of a runtime check that throws ArrayStoreException when it fails) and is in stark contrast to the invariance of generic types.

Answer (score 1):

As @Bozho has demonstrated the problem can be fixed, however to demonstrate what is going on consider this code:

```
public class Main {


  // This is the original version that fails because of type erasure in arrays
  private static <T> void foo(T[] t1, T[] t2) {

    t2[0] = t1[0];
  }

  // The same method as foo() but with the type erasure demonstrated
  private static void foo2(Object[] t1, Object[] t2) {

    // Integer[] should not contain String 
    t2[0] = t1[0];
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] stringArray = new String[]{"1", "2", "3"};
    Integer[] integerArray = new Integer[]{4, 5, 6};

    foo2(stringArray, integerArray);
  }

}
```

This is all to do with the fact that arrays in Java are covariant, whereas generics are not. [There is an interesting article about it here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255.html). A quick quote says it all:

> Arrays in the Java language are
>   covariant -- which means that if
>   Integer extends Number (which it
>   does), then not only is an Integer
>   also a Number, but an Integer[] is
>   also a Number[], and you are free to
>   pass or assign an Integer[] where a
>   Number[] is called for. (More
>   formally, if Number is a supertype of
>   Integer, then Number[] is a supertype
>   of Integer[].) You might think the
>   same is true of generic types as well
>   -- that List is a supertype of List, and that you can pass a
>   List where a List is
>   expected. Unfortunately, it doesn't
>   work that way.
>
> It turns out there's a good reason it
>   doesn't work that way: It would break
>   the type safety generics were supposed
>   to provide. Imagine you could assign a
>   List to a List. Then
>   the following code would allow you to
>   put something that wasn't an Integer
>   into a List:

```
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> ln = li; // illegal
ln.add(new Float(3.1415));
```

Because ln is a List, adding a Float to it seems perfectly legal. But if ln were aliased with li, then it would break the type-safety promise implicit in the definition of li -- that it is a list of integers, which is why generic types cannot be covariant.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler has inferred the type T for you and probably chosen `Object`.

You can specify the type if necessary using the following syntax:

```
MyClass.<String>foo(stringArray, integerArray); // Compiler error.
```

Combining arrays and generics is universally terrifying. By way of illustration I present Angelika Langer's Generics FAQ: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html